# How can I push code to a scratch org that belongs to an installed package?

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package, namespace, cumulusci

I am working on an application that is built from several separate unlocked packages, managed through cumulusci. The packages all share the same namespace.

When cumulusci creates a development org it installs the listed dependencies as installed packages. The source from these dependencies are not pushed to these orgs.

When I need to make changes to a set of these installed packages I can only do it from the dev console. If I try to make changes through `sfdx force source push` in the respective cumulusci project for that package after connecting to the org I get a lot of `Type is not visible` errors.

I believe it is expecting these components to contain the namespace prefix i.e. `my_ns.MyClass.methodFromThatClass()`.

Is there a way to use sf/sfdx commands to push source to these installed packages from their actual source code without the explicit namespace prefix?